# Pandas Replace all values of column with the mean of only one group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```py
  solutionType       attribute
0        fixed       1
1        float       2
2        other       42
3        fixed       55
4        fixed       1010
5        float       2021
```

I want to replace all of the values in the `attribute` column with the mean of all the values that have `solutionType` `fixed`, so in the example above the result should look like:

```py
  solutionType       attribute
0        fixed       355.33
1        float       355.33
2        other       355.33
3        fixed       355.33
4        fixed       355.33
5        float       355.33
```

I am able to compute this value using the following

```
print(df.groupby('solutionType', as_index=False)['attribute'].mean())
```

and would like to feed the value for `fixed` into a call of `replace()` or `loc()`.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, you get the mean for all the solutionType's that you have.
You can use `.loc` to get the attribute value for the fixed solutionType:

```
val = df.groupby('solutionType', as_index=False)['attribute'].mean().set_index('solutionType').loc['fixed','attribute']
df['attribue'] = val
```

Which prints:

```
  solutionType  attribute  attribue
0        fixed          1   355.333
1        float          2   355.333
2        other         42   355.333
3        fixed         55   355.333
4        fixed       1010   355.333
5        float       2021   355.333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and interchange it whatever value you want to replace it with :

```
df.groupby('solutionType').mean().T['fixed']
```